# Jpeg too small: How to increase the size of the image

Tags: size, jpeg, compression

I have got acquainted with the images of the project "Small ESP Game Dataset" due to Luis von Ahn's Research Group at http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~biglou/resources/.

The databasis is fantastic. However, the size of the images (in Jpeg) is very small. Is there any automatic way to increase the size of these images without loosing so much the resoulution? It can be C++, Java, PHP, matlab...

By the way, I realized that the same happens with Facebook id photos at sites such as http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-prn1/161897_129453496320_4485548_q.jpg

I know that there are tools everywhere in C++, PHP, Java... Even in HTML I can do that very easily, but in general I am loosing a lot of quality. I can realize this problem by simply trying to increase just a little the size of these images using the image editor of windows.

In both cases, the Real images used in the games or in facebook are much larger, but not the ones kept in the internet or in this game database... In particular, in the case of the images of Game dataset, since it is the author that is making them available, it must have a way to do that! Am I loosing something? How do people deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot re-size a raster image to a larger size without losing quality.  It's impossible.

Now, there are many methods for doing this re-size fairly smoothly.  Bi-cubic interpolation is common.

To actually do the re-sizing, consider using ImageMagick or GD, both of which can be used in a variety of libraries, including PHP.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php